# Spring как открыть jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, rest

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

//

```
 package com.example.demo;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

//

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
logging.level.com=TRACE
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Хочу вывести содержимое index.jsp, в итоге по адресу http://localhost:8090/test выводится просто строка "index" в браузере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло добавление зависимости на jstl

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Добавление конфига в мой MvcConfiguration

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

И изменение RestController на Controller

Answer (score 0):

Используйте аннотацию [@Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) вместо [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html).

Comment: Ошибка There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config

Comment: Ищите в логах полный текст ошибки. Только по 500-у коду сказать ничего нельзя.

Comment: выдал исключение java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config 

я добавил зависимость на jstl
  `<dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>`

теперь  There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

 `WARN 11828 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`

Comment: У вас jsp-файлы лежат в /WEB-INF/view, а ищутся почему-то в /WEB-INF/view**s**

Comment: Видимо, я менял название уже после того как задал вопрос. В любом случае спасибо